# Why is this dockerized Postgres not able to authenticate with a password?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, docker

I am working on changes to an Alpine fork of the official Docker postgres image ( https://hub.docker.com/r/deinspanjer/docker-postgres95-alpine34/ ).  It has been working fine for a while, but I needed to do some fdw connections, and that required host authentication to be set up so the user mapping could have a password.

You can see the startup / initdb code in the [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/deinspanjer/docker-postgres95-alpine34/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) file, but the meat of the matter is this:

1. Takes advantage of the POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD environment variables
2. Before calling initdb, writes the plain password to /tmp/.pwfile and writes the line: `*:*:*:$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to ~/.pgpass (chmod 600).
3. Calls initdb passing the --pwfile=/tmp/.pwfile argument to try to get it to initialize the superuser with the desired password.
4. Alters the pg_hba.conf file to add an additional line for `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

The problem is, after initdb, it starts up the server listening only on localhost to continue with the rest of the bootstrapping, but when it tries to run `psql --username $POSTGRES_USER`, it gets an authentication failure.

The log indicates that it is using the .pgpass, so I'm wondering if the initdb isn't picking up the password right or something, but I've fought with it until late in the night tonight, and I haven't been able to crack it.

If anyone else might be able to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

If you want to try running the entrypoint script manually, here is how you can do it:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=testuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testpass -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="-A md5" -p 5432:5432 -it --rm --entrypoint bash deinspanjer/docker-postgres95-alpine34
# printenv | grep POSTGRES
# /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
```

Comment: I found a post on the postgres mailing list where someone mentioned using the `password` auth method for local and md5 for host, so I tried that, but no difference.

Comment: I've gotten it to work for the moment by changing the pg_hba.conf file to local trust during bootstrap and then setting the password via a SQL command then changing it back to password and starting up.  Still just something I'm not getting about the --pwfile argument.